# How to install pymol using anaconda (CondaHTTPError: HTTP 403 FORBIDDEN for url)

Tags: anaconda, bioinformatics, pymol

When I try to install pymol using `conda install -c schrodinger pymol-bundle` as the documentation instructs (https://pymol.org/2/), an error occurs, and I'm not able to solve it.

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages
pdb2pqr-2.1.2+pymol  | 236 KB    |                                                                                                                              |   0%
freemol-1.158        | 6 KB      |                                                                                                                              |   0%

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 403 FORBIDDEN for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/schrodinger/noarch/pdb2pqr-2.1.2 pymol-py_0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: 00:00.354925
CF-RAY: 72dee7c5fd0d3577-CNF

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 403 FORBIDDEN for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/schrodinger/noarch/freemol-1.158-py_2.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: 00:00.390000
CF-RAY: 72dee7c87ccb3565-CNF

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
```

I think it can be a license problem, and I have the pymol license .lic file on my computer, that I've used to install pymol from the windows installer before, but I don't know how to include the license in the anaconda installation command. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely experiencing the same issue as many other users. It seems like  Cloudflare's system outages are affecting installations.

Here is a related thread on conda's github:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11638